# C Program works for me but shows runtime error online

Tags: c++, c

The following code worked fine for me (code blocks 10.05) and showed no compile-time/runtime errors for various test cases.
But showed runtime error as I submitted it online on a programming website.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

/*

 Here comes newPos()

*/
int main()

{
int t,i,n,k,j;
scanf("%d",&t);
int* a;

for(i=0;i<t;i++)
{
    scanf("%d",&n);
    free(a);

    a=(int*) malloc(n);

    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        scanf("%d",&a[j]);
    scanf("%d",&k);

    printf("%d\n",newPos(a,n,k));

}


return 0;
}
```

And then I changed it into a .cpp file after making a few changes. 
i.e., instead of free(a) I used the statement, delete a; and instead of a=(int*) malloc(n), I used the statement, a=new int[n];
Then it executed successfully both on my compiler and online.

Comment: At the first iteration you are freeing a dangling pointer. Initialize `a` to `NULL`.

Comment: As you've found out 'works for me' != 'free of bugs'. It's a very important lesson for C or C++ programmers.

Comment: FYI, in C++ you should use `delete[]` (not `delete`) after `new T[n]`.

Comment: There really is no c++ in this code. Perhaps the c++ tag should be removed.

Comment: @drescherjm Below the program i have included how i changed the dynamic allocation to c++ and it worked.

Comment: @all the C++ part is where I changed the malloc and free to new and delete. its below the program.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### First error:

You are not allocating enough memory to store `n` integer values. So you should change:

```
a=(int*) malloc(n);
```

to:

```
a=malloc(n * sizeof(int));
```

I have also removed the cast since it's useless and could hide a forgotten include.

#### Second error:

You must not free `a` before allocating memory. Free the memory only at the end of your loop.

#### C/C++ mix:

In the comments of this answer, people are talking about the need or not to cast, in particular in C++. In C, [you should not cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858).

If you are willing to do C++ code, you should use `new` and `delete` instead of `malloc` and `free`. Honestly, I don't know if a cast is needed in C++ when using `malloc`, because in C++, I always use `new`. But please, don't write C code with a C++ compiler. Choose between C and C++ depending on your needs.

Comment: That is not the problem.

Comment: the reason you stated is not the cause of the problem - see here - http://ideone.com/O4xkMj

Comment: @Acme: Neither problem is "the" problem, since there are at least two; but this is certainly one of them.

Comment: I see 2 problems: the malloc too small and the free of a before allocating. What's wrong?!

Comment: @MikeSeymour - the runtime error is not because of the cast which i want to say.

Comment: @Acme The problem is not the cast, it's the argument to `malloc`.

Comment: @Acme: Sorry, it wasn't clear what you meant by "that". There's no reason not to remove the pointless cast though.

Comment: @MikeSeymour - the answer initially did not contain any information regarding the wrong malloc argument and freeing of `a` before allocating - its been edited way later after other answers were posted.

Comment: @Acme I disagree, I only forgot the free in the initial answer.

Comment: @Maxime - Your answer did not contain that info before and that is why my first comment says what i said - you still have not noticed that the question is tagged `C` and `C++` both - your answer is still incomplete. In C++ the cast `is required`

Comment: @Acme If you read the question, it says that in C++ OP used `new` instead of `malloc`. So the cast isn't needed with `malloc` because it was only used in C.

Comment: @Acme, my initial answer said to change to `a=malloc(n * sizeof(int));`. And that's why I also said I didn't understand your comment. You read too fast.

Comment: We are talking language specific and not code specific. Using malloc with a cast is perfectly valid in C++.

Comment: If you are using C++, then you should be using `new` and `delete`, not `malloc` and `free` (and probably not use `printf`, but `cout`).

Comment: @MatsPetersson - When did i say what one should do - even the above answer does not mention what you said.

Comment: @Acme thank you for your suggestions for improving my answer. I am not the one who downvoted your answer though (I would not downvote a correct answer).

Comment: @Maxime - :) no harsh feelings.

Answer (score 3):

You are freeing before allocating:

```
free(a); // This can lead to Undefined Behavior because a is containing some junk value
a=(int*) malloc(n);
```

Also, no specific need to cast return type of malloc and check your malloc argument you are not specifying size in bytes correctly. But in C++ the case is required (Since you tagged both C and C++).

[Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605994#605994)

```
 a=(int*) malloc(n*sizeof(int));
```

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the mentioned allocation size problem, you can't `free(a)` unless you have either already allocated something, or have initialized `a` to have the value `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your argument to `malloc()` is wrong. The function has no idea what "unit" you're going to be using, so the unit for the argument is always "bytes". With C++'s `new[]` operator, that's operating a higher level in the language so it can take the type's size into account.

Thus, change your allocation to:

```
a = malloc(n * sizeof *a);
```

This removes [the pointless and annoying cast](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169), and also adds the missing `sizeof` to scale the argument by the number of bytes in each pointed-to object. This is a good form of `malloc()` usage to remember.

Also don't `free()` random pointers.